# What's the best way convert object to list in python?

Tags: python, types

So I receive parameter from json string, and convert it to Json object.

In this object, I have a field named `DepartmentIds`.

This `DepartmentIds` may an `int` or a `list` of `int`.

So I do a type check to see if `DepartmentIds` is instance of `int`.

```
if isinstance(DepartmentIds,int) :
    DepartmentIds = [DepartmentIds]
```

Any syntactic sugar exists?

Answer (score 3):

```
DepartmentIds = [DepartmentIds] if isinstance(DepartmentIds,int) else DepartmentIds
```

Not much better..